# C# Winforms - How can I have user controls (with children) hosted in a datagridview respond to mouse events?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've managed to host user controls in a DataGridView using something similar to the guide here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx My controls are a bit more complex and so I'm manually painting them.

The problem I'm having is that when the mouse goes over the cells in a DataGridView it obviously does not trigger the events for that control since it's a cell and not a control. My first solution here was ugly. I exposed the events activators like OnMouseEnter for the controls I was hosting and then used the events in the DataGridView like CellMouseEnter to call these exposed activators. The problem is that not only is this ugly, but it also doesn't work. This only fires for the top level control. So if my control has children, which it does, I'd have to somehow also pass the events on to them. This isn't too bad for MouseMove and stuff but I think manually calculating events like MouseEnter/MouseLeave for every child control is going to end up very error prone.

A second idea I had was to put the controls in the DataGridView, but instead of drawing them inside the DataGridView, I overlay an actual instances of the control on top of the DataGridView where the cells would be but this again seems pretty hacky and likely error prone.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do in a remotely clean fashion? It seems like it should be relatively trivial, but I've spent a lot of time on this and can't come up with a satisfactorily clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty simple. DataGridView supports controls being rendered as controls and not cells when they're in edit mode. The hosted controls will need to implement the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface, but once they do that it's a simple matter of verifying that it's a control you want to be able to interact with and then setting it to being in edit mode when mousing over it.

This is a specialized question so it's hard to general use code but after implementing the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface and setting up the Cell and Column classes for your control ( as discussed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ) here would be a simple way to hook in the editing:

```
    private void DataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
        {
            DataGridViewCell clicked = dataGridView1.Rows[hit.RowIndex].Cells[hit.ColumnIndex];
            if (typeof(YourDesiredControlType).IsAssignableFrom(clicked.ValueType))
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = clicked;
                dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
            }
            else
                dataGridView1.EndEdit();
        }
    }
```